# How to get all the files from a folder in sharepoint with there properties(Columns which were custom created by myself) via Powershell?

Tags: powershell, file, sharepoint, directory, sharepoint-online

How to get the column data from sharepoint folder for each file ?
I am able to get the names of all the files but i want to get the column details also(Column name - Hash, i created) how to get this value  ?
Below is the code till now (I am able to get the count even the names of all the files but not able to get the Hash column or any other column which i created for each file.)-

```html
$SiteURL = "Some SharePoint Url"
$FolderURL= "Some SharePoint Folder in shared documents"
  
  
Try {
    #Connect to PNP Online
    Connect-PnPOnline "Some SharePoint Url" -UseWebLogin
  
    #Get All Files from the Folder
    $FolderItems = Get-PnPFolderItem -FolderSiteRelativeUrl $FolderURL -ItemType File -Recursive
     
    Write-host "Total Number of Files in the Folder:" $FolderItems.Count
    ForEach($File in $FolderItems)
    {
      Write-Host  $File.Name | Format-Table   #*Similarly if i try $File.Hash = it is not working*
    }
}
catch {
    write-host "Error: $($_.Exception.Message)" -foregroundcolor Red
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this to get custom column values for the file:

```
 $FolderItems = Get-PnPFolderItem -FolderSiteRelativeUrl $FolderURL -ItemType File -Recursive
 ForEach($File in $FolderItems){
    $File.Name
    $fileURL=$FolderURL+"/"+$File.Name
    $fileItem=get-pnpfile $fileURL -AsListItem
    $fileItem['Column1']
    $fileItem['Column2']
}
```

Comment: rather than creating the file server relative Url by yourself you should use the property like $fileUrl = $File.ServerRelativeUrl